# changing the width of the rear view in SWRevealController

Tags: swrevealviewcontroller

I have my views designed in the storyboard.
When I slide out the menu, the rear view does not automatically resize to the width of the device.

How can i set the width of the view so that it matches up with the width defined by self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth?

thanks

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 9):

```
class SideMenuViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.width - 64
  }

}
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 6):

What I think Ant was looking for is the same I was trying to do when I stumbled upon this question: to make the rear view controller the size of the rear view width (in my case, I wanted this to happen since I had UI elements that had to be centered in the rear view). This worked for me:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.view.frame.size.width = self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth
    }
```

It went from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On your menu bar view controller paste below line on viewdidload method

```
Objective C

    self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.size.width-100;

Swift

self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.width-100
```

code working fine on all screen.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code into Menu Controller

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.view.frame.size.width = self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.view.frame.size.width = self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth
}
```

It can work with any menu. Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Just set rearViewRevealOverdraw to 0 right after you set reveal width property. for an example,

```
self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 300 //put the width you need   
self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0
```

Comment: self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0

it works

Answer (score 0):

I wrote di swift 3 statements in the viewDidLoad of the my MasterController, where I programmatically configure SWRevealViewController (FrontController and RearController) and assign SWRevealViewController() to UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window?.rootViewController, but it it would work also in the viewDidLoad of your initial UIViewController

```
let revealController = SWRevealViewController()

// settings to show full screen menu

// set width menu to screen size 
revealController.rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.width 
// hide totally shadow 
revealController.frontViewShadowOffset = CGSize.zero 
revealController.frontViewShadowOpacity = 0 

// optional settings

// no overdraw when dragging
revealController.rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0

// no displacement when animating or dragging the content
revealController.rearViewRevealDisplacement = 0
```